# Обособляется ли сочетание "пользуясь случаем"?

Tags: пунктуация

По моим данным, выражение "пользуясь случаем" классифицирует как наречное всего один словарь, да и то какой-то захудалый. Хотелось бы компенсировать недостаток словарных статей авторитетными мнениями присутствующих.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Пользуясь случаем,хочу передать привет друзьям".  Здесь используется устойчивый оборот на основе деепричастия, который всегда обособляется. По значению он близок к вводным словам, так как передает информацию второго плана. Обратим также внимание на расположение оборота в начале или в середине предложения, которое способствует его обособлению.

Для сравнения можно привести примеры  фразеологических оборотов, которые являются необособленными обстоятельствами образа действия и расположены во второй части предложения: Спешу к вам голову сломя. Нельзя сидеть  сложа руки. Всю ночь он провёл  не смыкая глаз. Будем работать  засучив рукава.  Все трое сидели повесив нос. Эти обороты входят в структуру простого предложения (тема - рема), то есть являются основным сообщением, их нельзя изъять из предложения.

Comment: София, это скорее клише, чем фразеологизм. Почему "он близок к вводным словам, так как передает информацию второго плана". Я пользуюсь случаем (в прямом значении) и я передаю привет. Обычный деепричастный оборот, часто используемый в эпистолярном жанре, значит, клише.

Comment: О терминологии. Фразеологизм - понятие сложное, имеющее разные виды классификаций. Выделяются различные виды оборотов: идиомы-сращения (бить баклуши, спустя рукава), фразеологические единства(грызть гранит науки, плыть по течению), фразеологические сочетания (сгорать от любви, нетерпения, стыда), фразеологические выражения (всего хорошего, до новых встреч). А клише - речевой стереотип, стандарт речи. Строго говоря, вся наша речь – это тоже клише. Оборот "пользуясь случаем (моментом)"  обладает главными признаками фразеологизма (в широком смысле) - устойчивостью и воспроизводимостью.

Comment: Об информации второго плана. Я имею в виду не переносное значение, а добавочный характер оборота, который, скорее, можно отнести к словам этикета (а эту область обслуживают вводные слова).

Comment: София, вот вторая часть Вашего ответа верна: фразеологизмы являются необособленными обстоятельствами образа действия. И примеры верны. А вот "Пользуясь случаем,хочу ..." - не фразеологизм, потому и обособляется. Употребляется выражение не только в эпистолярном жанре, структура его не фиксирована. Можно сказать: Пользуясь уникальным случаем ...Пользуясь возможностью...Пользуясь удобным случаем...Пользуясь случаем привлечь общее внимание...Не могу не воспользоваться представившимся случаем... и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

А при чём здесь словари? Это не фразеологизм, вполне свободное сочетание.Чаще всего это деепричастный оборот и поэтому обособляется,особенно если стоит перед сказуемым, но если тесно примыкает к сказуемому и стоит после него, возможна функция наречия:Он купил его пользуясь случаем = по случаю, случайно.

Comment: Единственный вариант, когда оборот не обособляется, указан Вами. Это "Он купил его пользуясь случаем". Дело не в тесном единстве (между глаголом и оборотом находиться местоимение), а в структуре и интонации предложения - именно такая структура и интонация  является нормой. Но позицию в конце предложения оборот занимает редко, поэтому вариант кажется искусственным.Обычно мы так и говорим: он купил его по случаю.

Comment: Так это банальный деепричастный оборот?! М-мда-а-а... случай прямо-таки анекдотический... если не сказать клинический. В критичности состояния с ним может соперничать разве что такой прецедент.
 
У студентов разных курсов спрашивают:

 — Сколько будет дважды два? 

 Первокурсник (не задумываясь): 

 — Четыре! 

 Второкурсник (посмотрев в шпору): 

 — Четыре. 

 Третьекурсник (воспользовавшись калькулятором): 

 — Четыре.. 

 Четверокурсник (пропустив через компьютер):

 — Четыре... 

 Пятикурсник: 

 — Я вам что, все константы должен помнить?!

Comment: Ну как не отметить @Noir! Есть склонность - не скромничайте. Ждём продолжения. А чтобы это относилось к тематике форума, пусть студенты будут филологами, тем более, что это правдоподобно: они, как правило, в арифметике не сильны! (извините: я никого не задел ненароком?)